# Openconnect VPN where host contains "/" character not working as expected

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openconnect

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and I need to create a VPN connection with `openconnect` (Pulse Network Connect).

I have installed the necessary packages:

```
network-manager-openconnect
network-manager-openconnect-gnome
```

but the problem is that when I configure the VPN the host I need to access contains a `/` character: `vpn.domain.com/connect`, so I add that host and when I enter the connection screen the host is `vpn.domain.com` and so I get an error and it says `XML response has no "auth" node`.

Is there a way to make it understand that it has to connect to `vpn.domain.com/connect`?
I tried it on a VM with KDE and from the KDE network manager it works and it detects `vpn.domain.com/connect` correctly.

Thanks